# Using brackets for proximity search "Tolkien.{0,300}Martin" doesn't work with line breaks. Workaround?

Tags: regex, search, character, brackets, proximity

Often I look for authors being commented/cited near each other. However, most of the times I am searching PDFs which have lots of line breaks.

For short words I use \s+ to handle the line breaks, but I don't know how to add this function when using proximity search based on brackets

```
\bTolkien.{0,300}Martin\b.
```

If they are in same line ok, but often 200 characters will lead to line breaks. So, is there a way to add the logic of the `\s+` in order that any character inside `.{0,300}` could ignore line breaks?

Doing so, I could find

```
\bTolkien.{0,300}Martin\b|\bTolkien.{0,300}Martin\b
```

despite of having line breaks through the `.{0,300}` characters.

Many thanks,
Cadu

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample of text and also specifying the programming language you're using.

Comment: I search English and Portuguese, but doesn't matter since the authors are written equal in both languages. See the expression: Habermas.{0,100}Weber|Weber.{0,100}Habermas. It would find the sentence: Habermas theory is about communication and it is more useful than Weber action theory. But if you insert a line break after "it is more" the game is over, no matches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what regexp language you are using, but in principle you are looking for something like this:

```
(?:.|\n){0,300}
```

or just

```
(.|\n){0,300}
```

That is an OR between `.` (which is any char except newline) and `\n' (newline).

You may need backslashes: `\(.\|\n\)` depending on your language. (You may even need doubling the backslashes.)

Oh, I see you are using | without backslash so I guess you do not need any backslash.

(BTW, you forgot to change the order between the two authors in the alternate regexp.)

Comment: The first version could be a little bit faster since it does not produce submatches.

Comment: Personally I prefer searching Zotero through Google since that is much faster. That requires though that the database you use is open for anyone to read. (And I do not know if Google indexes PDF-files in Zotero.)

Comment: Thanks for answers! The point of using Regex inside Zotero is that you can organize collections from that, not only search for the content.

Comment: @user3570966 Collections? Do you mean "saved searches"?

Comment: Saved searches, but from their results I create colections. Although I have my manual collections, I prefer search index content and create "logical" collecions. The process from saved searches to collections is drag'n'drop

Comment: I see. You could of course also save links corresponding to Google searches. (Using Google search currently requires some programming though to make it useable.)